# Selecting "ALL" in a query using a list of variables

Tags: mysql, bash

My first (simplified) script mysql_script.sh is:

```
#!/bin/bash
/usr/bin/mysql --password=**** --database=mydb<<EOMYSQL
SELECT SUM(usd) FROM mytable WHERE country=$VAR
INTO OUTFILE "oufile_$VAR.txt" FIELDS TERMINATED BY ';';
EOMYSQL
```

The first script is called from the second one:

```
#!/bin/bash
list=( 30 50 60 )
for L in "${list[@]}"
do
  VAR=${L} ./mysql_script.sh
done
```

It works fine, but now I need to get a 4th query with the results for `$VAR=*`, or `$VAR=30 or 50 or 60`. As VAR is the code of every country in my DB, I need the value of SUM(usd) for "all countries".
How can I express that?

I tested `'%%'` and `'*'` without success.

Thanks,

---

EDITED for (I hope) better understanding

Comment: Its not clear what exactly you are expecting? Can you please tell little more?

Comment: You are not showing what mysql_script.sh does, is there anything here that is mysql related or is it a pure bash question, not clear

Comment: Still not clear what you mean by "%%" and "*".  Can you also add to your post an example of output from mysql_script.sh?   Your question is still unlear on other areas such as what does "all countries" mean?  is 30, 50 etc a country?

Comment: Imagine my MySQL table has two columns: country and usd. I have 3 countries coded as 30, 50 and 60. When I run the first script I get 3 outputs, corresponding to counties 30, 50 and 60. Now, I need the mysql query to select all countries at the same time, by adding and expression in my list definition, someting like `list= (30 50 60 * )` in order to get 4 files, corresponding to countries 30, 50, 60, and 30+50+60.

Comment: @jm_ Can you just paste in your description a sample of what "oufile_$VAR.txt"  looks like?  (also wouldn't you get a filename with the character `*` in it? its leagal but not the best idea)

Comment: @nhed The output file content is irrelevant here, as it is just the result of the query. What indeed matters is the name of the file: as you mention including `"*"` as a part of the name is a bad idea. Nevertheless, `"*"` is not working as an expression to select "all countries", in my example. Thats precisely what I am asking for! How to add an expression in the list that would express all values of the variable in the database.

Comment: @jm_ ok, removing my answer as it is not what you asked for

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
#!/bin/bash
list=( 30 50 60 country)
for L in "${list[@]}"
do
  VAR=${L} ./mysql_script.sh
done
```

this will result in `where country=country` which will always be true and thus return a sum of all rows.

Handling ORs would get trickier and I'd say at that point you'd be well served to move past bash into as scripting language like perl or python.

Comment: @llion : thanks, that's the neat solution I was trying to guess. And yes, should start with perl. After mastering mysql and R thought...